# Piped awk command works as one-liner but not in loop

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a part of a script that isn't working as expected. It's supposed to take a list of newline-delimited episode paths in the format "/volume1/Shared Files/Cartoon/Show Name/Show Name SXX/file.mkv" (quotes included in the list file), run those files through mediainfo and append the UID to each line.

I can obtain the UID with the one-liner

```
/volume1/@appstore/nzbdrone/bin/mediainfo "/volume1/Shared Files/Cartoon/Show Name/Show Name SXX/file.mkv" | grep Unique | awk '{print $4}'
```

However, when executing the following code:

```
while read line; do
echo $line
/volume1/@appstore/nzbdrone/bin/mediainfo $line | grep Unique | awk '{print $4}' > $WorkingDir/output2.txt
echo `/volume1/@appstore/nzbdrone/bin/mediainfo $line | grep Unique | awk '{print $4}'`
var1=`echo /volume1/@appstore/nzbdrone/bin/mediainfo $line | grep Unique | awk '{print $4}'`
echo $var1
done < $WorkingDir/output.txt
```

I get the following output:

```
"/volume1/Shared Files/Cartoon/Show Name/Show Name SXX/file.mkv"


"/volume1/Shared Files/Cartoon/Show Name/Show Name SXX/file.mkv"


"/volume1/Shared Files/Cartoon/Show Name/Show Name SXX/file.mkv"


"/volume1/Shared Files/Cartoon/Show Name/Show Name SXX/file.mkv"


"/volume1/Shared Files/Cartoon/Show Name/Show Name SXX/file.mkv"


"/volume1/Shared Files/Cartoon/Show Name/Show Name SXX/file.mkv"
```

I know this wouldn't append the UIDs where I want, this is just an attempt at debugging. I'd expect at least one of those two blank lines between each echo $line would contain the UID. I don't know where it's going wrong :/

(running under bash on a Synology DS412+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double quotes are being read into the `line` variable and passed as part of the parameter to `mediainfo`. I never like using `read` for reading whole lines, preferring to use the `line` command instead.

You should remove the quotes from the input and instead use:-

```
while line=`line`; do
. . . . . .
/volume1/@appstore/nzbdrone/bin/mediainfo "$line" | grep Unique | awk '{print $4}' > $WorkingDir/output2.txt
. . . . . .
```

You should double-quote all instances of `$line`, not just in the line I have shown.

Note that `line` reads lines precisely, including the leading and trailing blanks which `read` strips.

Comment: Updated to:

`while line=`line`; do
echo $line
/volume1/@appstore/nzbdrone/bin/mediainfo "$line" | grep Unique | awk '{print $4}' > $WorkingDir/output2.txt
echo `/volume1/@appstore/nzbdrone/bin/mediainfo "$line" | grep Unique | awk '{print $4}'`
var2=`echo /volume1/@appstore/nzbdrone/bin/mediainfo "$line" | grep Unique | awk '{print $4}'`
echo $line
echo $var2
done < $WorkingDir/output.txt`

But I now get `/volume1/Tom/Scripts/BaconSonarr/xseednzb-0.1.2.sh: line 25: line: command not found
`

Comment: I presume that your loop starts at the 25th line of your script. It looks like you don't have the `line` command installed: verify by typing `type line` or `which line`. In Ubuntu it is part of the **util-linux** package, installed by default. If you can't find it you can use `head -n1` instead, so the first line becomes `while line=$(head -n1); do` (I have used $() notation to stop confusion with the back-quote for embedded code, but you can use back-quotes in your script).

Comment: This is running on a Synology, they're pretty sparse by default compared to a full distro. I tried the `head -n1` first but it caused an infinite loop of empty lines.
Next installed util-linux via ipkg, reverted to the code you originally suggested and it's working as expected! Thanks very much :)